# не работает max_element

Tags: c++

почему max_element работает неправильно ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

оно вывело 6 вместо наибольшего элемента 7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, mx;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[9]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
        
    }
    mx = *max_element (arr, arr);
    cout << arr[mx];
}
```

Comment: `mx = *max_element(arr, arr + n); cout << mx;`

Comment: max = *max_element(arr, arr + n); не работает, выдаёт a value of type "int *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"

Comment: https://ideone.com/iIaB74

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, mx;
    cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    mx = *max_element (arr, arr+n);
    cout << mx;
    delete[] arr;
    }
```